# Video streaming from drone to multiple Android phones

Tags: ardupilot, video

I have an Ardupilot drone with a 5.8GHz video transmitter - xf5804 which sends video to goggles. I would like to be able to stream my video to multiple Android smartphones in real time (latency of 1-3 seconds is acceptable) no matter where they are. I assume I need a server that will somehow get the video stream from the drone and then will provide it to the Android clients.

1. What are all the protocols, hardware and software (open-source; both on the server and on Android) elements that I can use for it?
2. Maybe there are tutorials on how to achieve that or read solutions?

Comment: You'll need the 5.8 GHz video receiver, an analog video capture device (composite video to USB dongles are cheap), and some PC of some sort to encode the stream.  WebRTC is the way to go if you need very low latency, and can afford the server(s) for it.